# Binding DropDownListFor helper to a dictionary

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm creating and populating a Dictionary and want to bind it to drop down list by using [DropDownListFor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee703573.aspx) helper method.

How do I map that dictionary's `key` and `value`  to dropdown?

It looks like I should be able to do something like:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(o => o.key, o => o.value, MyDictionary);
```

It seems like the first parameter should be a LINQ statement that maps key/value pair and second parameter is dictionary itself.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You cannot bind a dropdown list to a dictionary. It doesn't make sense. In order to generate a dropdown list you need 2 things: a scalar property to bind the selected value to and a collection to bind the options of the dropdown list. You only have the second of those two things which is the dictionary. So you cannot use a strongly typed helper.

You could do the following ugliness:

```
@Html.DropDownList("SelectedValue", new SelectList(MyDictionary, "Key", "Value"))
```

but of course a far better approach would be to use a view model:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public string SelectedValue { get; set; }
    public SelectList Values { get; set; }
}
```

which you would populate in your controller action:

```
public ActionResult Foo()
{
    Dictionary<string, string> dic = ...
    var model = new MyViewModel
    {
        Values = new SelectList(dic, "Key", "Value")
    };
    return View(model);
}
```

and finally in your strongly typed view:

```
@model MyViewModel
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.SelectedValue, Model.Values)
```

Comment: "You cannot bind a dropdown list to a dictionary. It doesn't make sense." Could you please explain why? Because we can easily do that in ASP.NET Web Forms.

Answer (score 2):

**You should try like this:**

In Controller

```
ViewBag.hour = new SelectList(Hours.Values);

void AddHours()
{
    Hours = new Dictionary<int, string>();
    Hours.Add(00, "00");
    Hours.Add(01, "01");
    Hours.Add(02, "02");
}
```

**In Views**

```
<div  class="col-md-2">
    @Html.DropDownList("Hours", new SelectList(ViewBag.hour.Items), "Hours", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "Hours" })
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I like your answer Darin. Thanks, it helped me come up with this solution. So far I've only tried it with strings, but it works good. Below is just a simple example. I also have extension methods (not shown here) for building View Model objects from Schema Model objects (for HttpGets) and for building Schema Model Objects from View Model objects (for HttpPosts).

**View Model**

```
public class Step4ViewModel
{
    public SelectList HowToBeContactedOptions { get; set; }

    public string HowToBeContacted { get; set; }
}
```

**Extension Method to make things easier and cleaner**

```
public static class EntityExtensionMethods
{
    public static Step4ViewModel PopulateDropDowns(this Step4ViewModel vm)
    {
        var howToBeContactedOptions = new Dictionary<string, string>
        {
            {"Email", "Email"}, 
            {"US Mail", "US Mail"}
        };

        vm.HowToBeContactedOptions = new SelectList(howToBeContactedOptions, "Key", "Value", vm.HowToBeContacted);
}
```

**Controller**

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Step4(Step4ViewModel vm)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return View(vm.PopulateDropDowns());
    }
}
```

**View**

```
@Html.ValidationSummary()
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.LabelFor(x => x.HowToBeContacted)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.HowToBeContacted, Model.HowToBeContactedOptions)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.HowToBeContacted)
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```